# Properly create hasMany/belongsTo record in old ember js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Using emberjs 1.5.1 and ember-data 1.0.0-beta.5.
I have couple of models:

```
App.Queue = DS.Model.extend({
    queue_id:   attr('number', {}),
    services:   hasMany('service', {})
});

App.Service = DS.Model.extend({
    queue:      belongsTo('queue', {}),
    service_id: attr('number', {}),
});
```

Here I create `queue` instance, save it, then try to create `service` instance and put created `queue` in `belongsTo` field

```
var new_queue = controller.store.createRecord('queue', {queue_id: element.Item1.Id});
new_queue.save();

var new_service = controller.store.createRecord('service', {
                                    queue: new_queue,
                                    service_id: subelement.Item1.Id,
                                });
new_service.save();
```

and after this I get `new_service` instance with the `queue` field equals `undefined`. Any ideas appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Considering this is a very old and no longer supported release of the framework, please take this answer as a best guess, based on my experience with Ember.js back then and the docs available for [1.10.0](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/creating-and-deleting-records/)

Following the docs, the result of createRecord can't be used directly. By using the promise returned from the save function and wrapping everything in a `.then` callback, you should be able to achieve what you're looking for.

```
var new_queue = controller.store.createRecord('queue', {
    queue_id: element.Item1.Id
});

new_queue.save().then(function(new_queue_record) {
    var new_service = controller.store.createRecord('service', {
        queue: new_queue_record,
        service_id: subelement.Item1.Id,
    });

    new_service.save();
});
```

Comment: Thx but the queue field is still `undefined`

Comment: Which version of Ember Data are you using?